# How to control the order of file types in tkfiledialog for different windows platforms

Tags: python, windows, dialog, tkinter

I'm using tkfiledialog to ask my user for input/output files. The folder is rather cluttered, so it's a real boon to use the filetypes option to restrict the view to files of one type. Everything was working fine on XP, then appeared to stop working on win7. Instead of a filtered view of the folder, I got all_files, which was consistent with the filetype listbox, which said all files. I could change what was displayed through the dropdown, but I'd prefer to have the right type appearing first off as the default.

This is the investigation program I've been using to find out what's going on.

```
import Tkinter as tki
import tkFileDialog as tkf

root = tki.Tk()
root.withdraw()

for thing in ['.json','json','*.json','.txt;.csv','*.txt;*.csv']:

    # cfname = tkf.askopenfilename(title=thing,
                             # filetypes=[('filter',thing),('all','*')])

    cfname = tkf.askopenfilename(title=thing,
                                 filetypes=[('all','*'), ('filter',thing)],
                                 initialfile='*.csv')
```

What I found is that both XP and 7 do work, but XP presents the first field in the filetypes argument as the default in the filetype listbox, while 7 uses the last. Setting an initialfile doesn't control which gets selected, just overrides what gets shown, while not affecting the listbox, so results in an inconsistent display, even worse.

Am I missing some sort of switch in tkfiledialog to control what gets put into the filetype listbox default?

I could omit the all option, then tkfiledialog only has a choice of one, but it's a useful backup I'd prefer to keep.

If I get desperate, I can of course inspect platform.win32_ver()[0], which will be 'XP' or '7' respectively, and then flip my filetypes list. But before I do that, am I missing something that will work across all platforms?